# How to set the time in php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code.

I want to add the time where i add the date but how  i need to know how to add time in this script.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
From : <input type="text" name="d1" class="tcal" value="" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<table id="resultTable" data-responsive="table" style="text-align: left; width: 400px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th> Birtday </th>
     <th> Name </th>
     <th> Gender </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php
    include('connect.php');
    if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1="0000-00-00"; }; 
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE date = :a");
    $result->bindParam(':a', $d1);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
  ?>
<tr class="record">
    <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
} 
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is code where i want to add the time how ?

```
if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1=date('Y-m-d')$d1=time('H:i:s'); };
```

May i know what change should i do to add the time in my script ?

Comment: $d1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")

Comment: [`time`](http://www.php.net/time) does not take any parameters.

Comment: hey @putvande how what parameters i add and where add the parameters of timestamp in this script..

Comment: In your original code, you are confusing date() and time() functions. time() simply returns the current timestamp (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT). date() is used to format both dates (e.g., 'Y-m-d') and times (e.g., 'H:i:s'). Use date() to get both formatted dates and formatted times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET["d1"]))
{ 
     $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; 
} 
else 
{ 
     $d1=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

For more look at php reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

**Update as per your comment's Question:**

Here lets take an example of the input field and also how to show the value of date inside it. Your code will be like this:

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>" />
```

**Update 2 for the SQL Query comment:**

first make a sql query in a php variable that you will use for querying database:

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = "SELECT * FROM birthday  where date <= $current_date";
```

For more information regarding mysql handling [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch--net-10188) is a great tutorial and [this one](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/) as well:

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); };
```

Comment: hey @pinu how what parameters i add and where add the parameters of timestamp in this script. to recive data from mysql database

Comment: To display time you can write the code
<?php echo date('H:i',strtotime($row['date'])); ?>

Comment: you visit here then you understand easily what i want http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php ok i want to get data from mysql time to time when i open page then i get the 11:00 AM data if i open the page on 1:PM then i get the data 11:00 AM to 1:00PM data i want like this